# Using google cloud registry with docker while offline

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, google-cloud-registry

I'm using Google Cloud Registry, associating with Docker using `gcloud auth configure-docker`.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/configure-docker

However, when my computer is offline and I run `docker-compose up` I get an error where it tries to communicate/authenticate with Google.

how can I use docker offline now that I've started using GCR?

```
$ docker-compose up --build --force-recreate -d
Building solr
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.docker-helper) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a
different account:

  $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT

to select an already authenticated account to use.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 74, in _execute
  File "subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
  File "subprocess.py", line 418, in run
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/bin/docker-credential-gcloud', 'get']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 129, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
  File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 35, in get
  File "site-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 87, in _execute
dockerpycreds.errors.StoreError: Credentials store docker-credential-gcloud exited with "".

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 127, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1080, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1076, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 475, in up
  File "compose/service.py", line 342, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose/service.py", line 1082, in build
  File "site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 251, in build
  File "site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 307, in _set_auth_headers
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 96, in resolve_authconfig
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 146, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
docker.errors.DockerException: Credentials store error: StoreError('Credentials store docker-credential-gcloud exited with "".',)
[26419] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker-compose will read your YAML file to [configure your application’s services](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) , so if in your YAML you are using a Docker image or a personalized images and you don't have them on local, docker will try download them from the principal registry in your configuration, in this case Google Cloud Registry and if your are offline you will get an error.